# Dynamically create nth-child selectors based on props to a Material-UI component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-selectors, material-ui

I'm trying to customise the Material UI slider component (specifically its `marks` prop) to show the number of occurrences for each data object within the `marks` array.

Basically I want the slider to look something like this:
[image: screenshot showing marks]

I've achieved this like so:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
      backgroundColor: "black",
      "&:nth-child(4)": {
        height: 8
      },
      "&:nth-child(6)": {
        height: 3
      },
      "&:nth-child(8)": {
        height: 5
      },
...
    },
  }
});
```

But I want to be able to create this dynamically. I can pass my `marks` prop to `makeStyles` like so: `const classes = useStyles(marks);`, and then use the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
      backgroundColor: "black",
      "&:nth-child(4)": {
        height: (marks: {occurrences: number}[]) => marks[0
        ].occurrences
      },
      "&:nth-child(6)": {
        height: (marks: {occurrences: number}[]) => marks[1
        ].occurrences
      },
      "&:nth-child(8)": {
        height: (marks: {occurrences: number}[]) => marks[2
        ].occurrences
      },
...
    },

  }
});
```

This again achieves the desired result, but what if I have an unknown number of objects within my `marks` array? Is there a way to dynamically generate the `nth-child` selectors?

I've made a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/percentage-slider-dynamic-marks-4o0m4?file=/src/DynamicMarks2.tsx

Answer (score 2):

I've managed it with the following code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: (marks: { occurrences: number }[]) => {
    const marksReduce = marks.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [`&:nth-child(${4 + index * 2})`]: { height: cur.occurrences }
      };
    }, {});

    return {
      width: 200,
      "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
        backgroundColor: "black",

        ...marksReduce,

        [`&:nth-child(${4}n)`]: {
          height: marks[0].occurrences
        }
      },
      "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
        display: "none"
      }
    };
  }
});

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/percentage-slider-dynamic-marks-4o0m4?file=/src/DynamicMarks3.tsx
```